# IE10 gray square on click in Windows 8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

How to disable this horrible design stuff of microsoft programmers? 
It's happens when I click on links.
Another horrible feature is dotted border on input elements. In past, this border disappear by adding outline: none to focus state of inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following meta

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
```

It works for IE10/Windows Phone 8, not sure about Windows 8.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been trying to debug this for a couple of hours. How did you find out about this, so I can maybe see future issues.

Comment: From here http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx#step5 "The tag is specific to Internet Explorer 10 on Windows Phone, and does not apply to Internet Explorer 10 on Windows."

Comment: This didn't work for me in IE10 on Win7, **but** `a:active{background-color:transparent !important;}` did

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason the meta tag didn't work for me on Windows 7 IE10, and I had to set

```
a:active{
  background: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background: inherit;
```

Above does not work if your background color is differently set or has multiple settings.

Below is fail proof.

```
a:active{
background: none;
}
```